# .htaccess /?tag= to /?product_tag= redirecting retaining the query

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm on Apache using Wordpress. 
I use to run the standard Wordpress tag system, which uses the `/?tag=`  format.

Recently I migrated to Woocommerce, which uses the `/?product_tag=`  format.
Is there any way to automatically redirect a visit that queries the `/?tag=xxx` page to `/?product_tag=xxx`  whilst still retaining the query intact?

For example, Googlebot indexed all my pages like so:

```
https://wwww.domain.com/fruit/apples/?tag=red
```

So when Googlebot visits this url again, it will instead be redirected to

```
https://wwww.domain.com/fruit/apples/?product_tag=red
```

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)?tag=(.*?)$ /$1product_tag=$2 [R=301,L]
```

but it does not work. It seems the `?` character is causing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the `RewriteRule` first portion only matches against the part of the URL, before the query string.

You need to use `RewriteCond` and regex back-reference to identify the query string `tag`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tag=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1?product_tag=%1 [R=301,L]
```

`$1` is the regex back-reference to `(.+)`, and `%1` is the regex back-reference to `([^&]+)`.